# Chrome doesn't remember a certain Google password

Tags: google-chrome

I have several Google accounts set up in my Chrome browser.

Chrome remembers all of them along with their password. If I want to access my account, I click my name and it automatically inserts my name.

However, there is one account for which Chrome doesn't store the password.
Chrome offers the account when I type the first letter, but when I click it, it doesn't auto-fill the password. I have to enter the password manually each time.

I don't see any setting in Chrome to change that.

---

Per suggestion, I  installed Chrome in a new virtual machine in order to start from scratch. I wanted to be asked if Chrome should save (and thus sync) the credentials.
When I logged in to Gmail, Chrome did NOT ask me if it should save the credentials.

So, I guess the mail address is in the "Ignore list" otherwise Chrome would ask me if it should be saved.
But, it is not shown in the Ignore list, so I can't remove it from there so I guess that's a real Google bug.

Also, changing the password doesn't trigger the "Update password?" dialog in Chrome.

Comment: @PatLeahy It's the GMail Log in page. I don't think your comment makes sense, so I would advise to remove it so that it doesn't distract?

Comment: Disable synchronization of the account and then enable it again. Google prompts for your creditentials and voila!

Comment: @KasperiKoski OMG!!! Make your comment the answer, please!!!! I will accept it. Your comment was the solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Chrome doesn't offer to save the password to the account which is signed into Chrome anymore: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/33580431?hl=en. It's stated that it's for security reasons, which I think is weird since it can store passwords to all other websites you're using and even credit card information.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `chrome://settings/passwords` in Google Chrome.
- Remove `accounts.google.com` from "Never Saved" (Please check the screenshot below).
- Login to your account. Google Chrome will ask to save your password.
- Save your password.

Next time, it will remember your password.
[image]

Comment: This is an IMPORTANT place to manage the passwords for the sites you go to using 1 particular Google Account, (it's a Gmail account probably).

Comment: @boyukbas The account in question is not listed under "Never saved".

Comment: I don't believe it is a Google bug. Your "edit" points that the issue is related to the account which you login to your chrome. Just check this page chrome://settings/passwords and find some google subdomain on "Never Saved" section. When you remove it, it should resolve your issue. That's all I can say.

Comment: @boyukbas GMail was not listed in "Never Saved". However, I have now removed ANY entries from "Never Saved", then logged out and logged in again. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have one more guess. Can you disable your chrome extensions and try it again?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest that you should remove the account from the "Never Saved" category.

> I have several Google accounts set up in my Chrome browser

If that doesn't work then there might be a limit of synchronization for Google accounts. I would suggest you read the following:

- [Gmail bandwidth limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518)
- [Sync limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2751577)

Google describes a solution as:

> Having multiple clients means every message gets downloaded multiple times, increasing bandwidth consumption exponentially. To manage your sync clients:
>
> Remove or disable unused sync clients and quit clients when not in use.

Changes made on one client or the web interface sync to all clients. So, avoid making large changes if you have multiple sync clients. Or decrease the amount of clients in use.

Comment: The account is not listed under "Never Saved".

Comment: And I can still add more credentials / syncs. So that is not the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are these actual Google  accounts, or accounts for Websites you go to in Chrome?

I have multiple login accounts for websites all saved in my Google account, and only some bookmarks I have saved seem to work with the browser password management.  This is because the developer of the website can disable password remembering of the browser for security purposes.

Is the account that's giving you trouble a login for some business you work for?  That may be the problem, and they actually want you to type the password in each time you log in.  This is so a family member, roommate, etc., can't go onto your computer and get into the work site.

Otherwise, if you are talking about a separate Google account, with its own actual Gmail account address, and the browser is not remembering the password for this particular Gmail account, you may have to bite the bullet here and reset the entire browser settings and then start entering the passwords in for all the Google accounts, and website accounts, and asking it to remember again.

Comment: Actual Google accounts.

Comment: Clearing all browser settings is not an option unfortunately, else I would have tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to passwords.google.com, make sure the website you need login information entered automatically for is listed there. If the website is listed there you can skip step 3.
2. Click on the "gear" icon at the top right at passwords.google.com and enable the two options: "Offer to save passwords" and "Auto sign-in".
3. My own Google Chrome version on my laptop does not allow syncing passwords, therefore the  way to add a website's login credentials to passwords.google.com is to navigate to the site you want to add, through Google's Chrome browser, via your cellphone or tablet, as Google Chrome browser on these devices definitely syncs with passwords.google.com.

   Enter your login credentials at the required website you have navigated to. Google Chrome will prompt you to save your login credentials via a dialog box. Select "Save".
4. If you revisit the link now, that you wanted to add login credentials for, they will have been saved for reuse.

[image: Google Not Asking For Password - solution]

Comment: It's not listed there.

Comment: Hi tmighty. If your login credentials are not listed at passwords.google.com, then you would follow all four of the steps I have listed above.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed Chrome in a new virtual machine and logged in with the account in question, and it didn't ask me to save the credentials. I guess the mail address is in the "Never Save" list, but it is not listed there, so I can't remove it from there.

Comment: Try following STEP 2 in my post. Click the Gear icon at passwords.google.com at the top right, and then enable the two options: "Offer to save passwords" and "Auto sign-in".

Comment: tmighty, you perhaps need to add your credentials to passwords.google.com. The certain way to do this is to use a Cellphone or Tablet with Google Chrome browser on it. Navigate to the site you want to add, enter your credentials at the site on your mobile device, and SAVE them.

Answer (score -1):

In Google Chrome, go to Settings and there is a Password Management category that you can go into and check all the accounts that Chrome has saved. See if your password is saved along with your account. If it is not, go to https://passwords.google.com where you can manually enter and save your password.

Comment: This might solve the issue.
For me; https://passwords.google.com isn't opening because my passwords are password protected.

Answer (score -1):

If your chrome browser does not have autofill off then it's not chrome which is having problem. The HTML have a property called "autocomplete", which if is set to  "OFF" will never let the browser manage the password or in other words remember the values.

Comment: It's only for ONE account where this is happening.

Answer (score -2):

If you're logged onto Chrome with the account you want to save the password for, then you won’t be able to.

I’m not sure why but Google and Gmail are set up so that Chrome doesn’t save the password for the account you’re logged onto in Chrome since it considers it as though you don’t need to save it because you’re already logged on.

It took me a while to understand this when it comes to Google passwords, saving them, and autofill of private info.

I understand the logic behind it because, if you needed to save the password for the account you’re already logged onto in Chrome, then technically you wouldn’t even be logged into that account at all given that you already have access to it and are saving passwords to account information from various websites on to that same account you’re hoping to save the password for.

It’s a weird circular logic but when you think about it, it kind-of makes sense, it’s just annoying because obviously you won’t be able to access the password for that account you’re logged into Chrome on.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". Grammar matters on SO, as does formatting and punctuation. SO isn't a forum or message board, it's more like an online reference book, where those things matter.